# When, if ever, and how, would Google, Yahoo, Bing, etc will add the new gTLD to their search results?

Tags: seo, domains, search-engines, top-level-domains

New domain names like .photos .gallery .repair etc are being released every month. I tried running a generic search for some things, and I could not find any of those in the results.

Any idea if they will ever integrate them into the search results? Will they be ranked higher than the .com domains? For example, if someone had stackphotos.com and now they got stack.photos - will the second domain be ranked higher than the first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any idea if they will ever integrate them into the search results?

Of course they will. Do you really think the search engines would omit an entire segment of websites just because their TLD is new? The search engines have readily indexed and ranked new TLDs as they emerged (i.e. .co, .biz). These new TLDs will be no exception.

> Will they be ranked higher than the .com domains?  For example, if someone had stackphotos.com and now they got stack.photos - will the second domain be ranked higher than the first?

TLD is one of many ranking factors. Just having a TLD that is relevant for a search term is *not* going to be enough to make the difference in rankings. Some people would like to speculate about "all things being equal" but in reality they are never equal so I won't get involved in that. (Plus it would only be speculation anyway).

Comment: How long it usually takes to integrate a domain results to the search?

Comment: I haven't seen anything to indicate a timeframe. My guess is they are available immediately. Google gets notice when a new TLD is available and I can't imagine it being difficult to be ready for a new TLD. It would most likely just be a matter of determining if it is a localized TLD (country specific) or not.

Answer (score 1):

All websites have to earn their Page Rank with Google, regardless of top-level domain extention.

As for the time frame, it is almost instant, as far as the public knows regarding how Google Search works from the backend.

Answer (score 1):

You can already find examples of the new tlds indexed.

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3A.guru

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3A.club