# Are new gTLDs negatively effected in SEO?

Tags: seo, top-level-domains

I have done my research, mainly using [this](http://moz.com/search-ranking-factors) as a source, and I have come to understand that there are certain aspects that can cause newer gTLDs, just by the indication that many of the newer gTLDs, such as `.directory`, will increase the total length of the full domain, therefore having a negative impact.

Are there other reasons why sites with newer gTLDs may rank lower? I understand that there is no set timeframe for search engines to add a new TLD to their search results (however it is assumed to be very short) from [this post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/60387/when-if-ever-and-how-would-google-yahoo-bing-etc-will-add-the-new-gtld-to), but would certain factors such as time since a gTLD has been implemented (the older the TLD possibly the more reliable/stable it is assumed to be) have any effect on SEO?

Comment: Hello: where did you read that a long domain name has a negative impact on SEO ?

Comment: I posted it as my first link, [but here is the link again](http://moz.com/search-ranking-factors)

Answer (score 2):

I studied the thing in 2012 based on `.museum` and published this article: http://blog.guillon.com/2012/09/googles-search-engine-is-ready-for-new.html

If `.museum` was considered as a long TLD, then I'd consider that SEO is not affected. Same for new gTLDs.

Answer (score 1):

New gTLDs have been created for a reason and Google can't apply a negative impact on SEO by default (even if they increase the length of the domain name and URLs).

As long as you use new gTLDs like wanted (i.e. `.lawyer` for a website about a lawyer or `.bar` for a bar website), there is no negative impact on SEO.

Moreover, you're right when you say that the age of a domain name is taken into account for SEO but if you buy a new domain name (and it's indexed by search engines tomorrow), whether you bought a `.com` or a `.bar`, it will have the same age for search engines. The date on which the gTLD has been implemented is not taken into account for SEO.

Comment: You could get point for using `.com` (or the tld of a country, like `.nl`) because those are simpler to remember. You get points for easy-to-remember urls, so that logic **could** extend to this.

Comment: For now, you're right but in the future, I think `.bar` will be easier to remember for users who will just search a bar on Google. That's why I didn't mention your point in my answer.