# Do .com websites get better SEO results than a .net website?

Tags: seo, domains

Nowadays a lot of `.com` websites are already taken. Can I expect the same natural SEO results for a `.net` website for example?

Comment: Surprisingly I can't find a duplicate for this question. We have several questions about newer TLDs [like this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/76656/are-domains-with-gtlds-ninja-guru-museum-etc-bad-for-seo), but you are asking about `.net` which is pretty old. Some of the answers to [How important is the domain name for SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3548/how-important-is-the-domain-name-for-seo) touch on this, but the question is a different question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google has [confirmed](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2015/07/googles-handling-of-new-top-level) that alternative gTLDs do not affect search rankings. However, using an uncommon TLD may affect CTR (click-through-rate).

SEOs tend to recommend .com domains because users are most familiar with them, as the  domain is often a signal of a site's credibility. At least amongst new users.

Since .net domains are very common, I would not hesitate from using one.

Answer (score 3):

For the most part, the domain zone has no effect on SEO, there are all depends on the site and its optimization, to some extent domainna zone affects, but on the factor to which subject matter the site is a global site or just one region, if you can make a shorter and more unique zone .net instead of .com, I would create a domain on .net

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, I have been using (.IN) extension for one of my website for a few years now and it ranks very well on Google India and Google US.